# json schema faker with fake pattern

Tags: json, faker, json-schema-faker

I'm using the [json-schema-faker](http://json-schema-faker.js.org/#gist/88ce79eafd3cc9e95b7eaec98349eb4e/0.4.3) and i'm using it with [Faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Faker) which allows me to get random "real" format values, like emails, image url etc.
this scheme works well:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "myPattern":{
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "pattern1||pattern2"
    },
    "image": {
      "type": "string",
      "faker": "image.city"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "myPattern",
    "image"
  ]
}
```

But what i really wants is that the `faker` will get a pattern like the property `myPattern` gets.
I've tried some variations but none works.
Some syntax I've tried:
`"faker": "image.city||image.food"`

```
  "faker": {
    "fake": {
      "pattern": "image.city||image.food"
    }
  }
```

-

```
  "faker": {
    "pattern": "image.city||image.food"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

when you use:

```
"faker": {
  "pattern": "image.city||image.food"
}
```

the code executed behind will be similar to this: `faker.pattern("image.city||image.food")`

To fix your specific case you need to wrap possible variations of faker calls as `oneOf`:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "myPattern":{
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "pattern1||pattern2"
    },
    "image": {
      "type": "string",
      "oneOf": [
        { "faker": "image.city" },
        { "faker": "image.food" }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "myPattern",
    "image"
  ]
}
```

It seems to be working now: http://json-schema-faker.js.org/#gist/9c5cb08965aeeb46b11ca6856251aa80/0.4.3